# grow a div vertically without a scroll bar

Tags: html, css

I have the following CSS code:

```
#maincol{
 background-color: #fff;  
 position: relative; 
 width:1360px;
 height:800px;
 padding:0px 0px 0px 30px;
 }

#widgetcontainer{
 background-color: #00386B;  
 position: relative; 
 width:1390px;
 height:100%;
 Margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
 Padding:0px 10px 0px 0px;
 Overflow:auto;


 }


.widget{
 background-color: #BAC6DE;  
 float:left;

 width:200px;
height:100%;
 margin:0px 10px 0px 0px;
 padding:0px 10px 0px 0px;
 }
```

I want to make code grown without the use of a scroll bar, so when the 100% is reached, the div continues to grow with the text. But i want to use the mainscroll bar in IE and not within the iFrame.

The HTML looks like this as you can see (if you put this in JFIDDLE) it adds a scroll bar:

```
<div id="wrapper" class="clearfix">


<div id="maincol">

<div id="widgetcontainer">


    <div class="widget">
    <div class="hover">



<!----------Start NAVIGATION PANEL----------->
<a href="TEAM HOME.htm">TEAM HOME</a>
<a href="BASE.htm" class="current">BASE LINKS PAGE</a>
<a href="EMAIL DRAFTS.htm">EMAIL DRAFT</a>
<!----------End NAVIGATION PANEL----------->


    </div> 

</div>



<!----------Start BASE Links----------->
<font size=5><strong><p>Please Enter Your First Title Here . . .. . .</p></strong></font>
<p><a href="Please Enter Your First Link Here . . ." target=_blank">Please Enter Your First Description Here . . .</a></p>
<P>A wonderful serenity has taken possession of my entire soul, like these sweet mornings of spring which I enjoy with my whole 

heart. I am alone, and feel the charm of existence in this spot, which was created for the bliss of souls like mine. I am so 

happy, my dear friend, so absorbed in the exquisite sense of mere tranquil existence, that I neglect my talents. I should be 

incapable of drawing a single stroke at the present moment; and yet I feel that I never was a greater artist than now. When, 

while the lovely valley teems with vapour around me, and the meridian sun strikes the upper surface of the impenetrable foliage 

of my trees, and but a few stray gleams steal into the inner sanctuary, I throw myself down among the tall grass by the 

trickling stream; and, as I lie close to the earth, a thousand unknown plants are noticed by me: when I hear the buzz of the 

little world among the stalks, and grow familiar with the countless indescribable forms of the insects and flies, then I feel 

the presence of the Almighty, who formed us in his own image, and the breath
<P>A wonderful serenity has taken possession of my entire soul, like these sweet mornings of spring which I enjoy with my whole 

heart. I am alone, and feel the charm of existence in this spot, which was created for the bliss of souls like mine. I am so 

happy, my dear friend, so absorbed in the exquisite sense of mere tranquil existence, that I neglect my talents. I should be 

incapable of drawing a single stroke at the present moment; and yet I feel that I never was a greater artist than now. When, 

while the lovely valley teems with vapour around me, and the meridian sun strikes the upper surface of the impenetrable foliage 

of my trees, and but a few stray gleams steal into the inner sanctuary, I throw myself down among the tall grass by the 

trickling stream; and, as I lie close to the earth, a thousand unknown plants are noticed by me: when I hear the buzz of the 

little world among the stalks, and grow familiar with the countless indescribable forms of the insects and flies, then I feel 

the presence of the Almighty, who formed us in his own image, and the breath
<P>A wonderful serenity has taken possession of my entire soul, like these sweet mornings of spring which I enjoy with my whole 

heart. I am alone, and feel the charm of existence in this spot, which was created for the bliss of souls like mine. I am so 

happy, my dear friend, so absorbed in the exquisite sense of mere tranquil existence, that I neglect my talents. I should be 

incapable of drawing a single stroke at the present moment; and yet I feel that I never was a greater artist than now. When, 

while the lovely valley teems with vapour around me, and the meridian sun strikes the upper surface of the impenetrable foliage 

of my trees, and but a few stray gleams steal into the inner sanctuary, I throw myself down among the tall grass by the 

trickling stream; and, as I lie close to the earth, a thousand unknown plants are noticed by me: when I hear the buzz of the 

little world among the stalks, and grow familiar with the countless indescribable forms of the insects and flies, then I feel 

the presence of the Almighty, who formed us in his own image, and the breath
<P>A wonderful serenity has taken possession of my entire soul, like these sweet mornings of spring which I enjoy with my whole 

heart. I am alone, and feel the charm of existence in this spot, which was created for the bliss of souls like mine. I am so 

happy, my dear friend, so absorbed in the exquisite sense of mere tranquil existence, that I neglect my talents. I should be 

incapable of drawing a single stroke at the present moment; and yet I feel that I never was a greater artist than now. When, 

while the lovely valley teems with vapour around me, and the meridian sun strikes the upper surface of the impenetrable foliage 

of my trees, and but a few stray gleams steal into the inner sanctuary, I throw myself down among the tall grass by the 

trickling stream; and, as I lie close to the earth, a thousand unknown plants are noticed by me: when I hear the buzz of the 

little world among the stalks, and grow familiar with the countless indescribable forms of the insects and flies, then I feel 

the presence of the Almighty, who formed us in his own image, and the breath
<P>A wonderful serenity has taken possession of my entire soul, like these sweet mornings of spring which I enjoy with my whole 

heart. I am alone, and feel the charm of existence in this spot, which was created for the bliss of souls like mine. I am so 

happy, my dear friend, so absorbed in the exquisite sense of mere tranquil existence, that I neglect my talents. I should be 

incapable of drawing a single stroke at the present moment; and yet I feel that I never was a greater artist than now. When, 

while the lovely valley teems with vapour around me, and the meridian sun strikes the upper surface of the impenetrable foliage 

of my trees, and but a few stray gleams steal into the inner sanctuary, I throw myself down among the tall grass by the 

trickling stream; and, as I lie close to the earth, a thousand unknown plants are noticed by me: when I hear the buzz of the 

little world among the stalks, and grow familiar with the countless indescribable forms of the insects and flies, then I feel 

the presence of the Almighty, who formed us in his own image, and the breath
<P>A wonderful serenity has taken possession of my entire soul, like these sweet mornings of spring which I enjoy with my whole 

heart. I am alone, and feel the charm of existence in this spot, which was created for the bliss of souls like mine. I am so 

happy, my dear friend, so absorbed in the exquisite sense of mere tranquil existence, that I neglect my talents. I should be 

incapable of drawing a single stroke at the present moment; and yet I feel that I never was a greater artist than now. When, 

while the lovely valley teems with vapour around me, and the meridian sun strikes the upper surface of the impenetrable foliage 

of my trees, and but a few stray gleams steal into the inner sanctuary, I throw myself down among the tall grass by the 

trickling stream; and, as I lie close to the earth, a thousand unknown plants are noticed by me: when I hear the buzz of the 

little world among the stalks, and grow familiar with the countless indescribable forms of the insects and flies, then I feel 

the presence of the Almighty, who formed us in his own image, and the breath
<!----------End BASE Links----------->



    <br clear=all>

</div>


</div>
```

But looking at the past questions im not sure if it can be done?

Any thoughts?